# How to rotate objects in pstricks without shifting them?

Tags: pstricks, rotating

I'm trying to draw an image with pstricks (an experiment schematics) and I'm having a hard time rotating stuff. I'm using psrotate and everytime I rotate something it has its position shifted as well. Is there a way to rotate something with respect to its center? I'm trying to rotate simple objects like squares and rectangles...

thank you very much.

```
 \documentclass[crop=true]{standalone} 
 \usepackage{pst-plot}
 \usepackage{pstricks-add}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
%
 \begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.1)(20.1,25.1)

\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](0,0)(20,25)
%
\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](1,15)(19,24)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, linewidth=0.06cm,linecolor=gray](5,17)(10,22)(15,17)%prisma


\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](1,1)(19,14.5)
\pspolygon[linewidth=0.06cm,linecolor=gray](4,2)(10,8)(16,2)%prisma


\pscircle*[linecolor=LTCearthred](7.5,5.5){3pt}
\pscircle*[linecolor=LTCearthred](12.5,5.5){3pt}
\pscircle*[linecolor=LTCearthred](10,2){3pt}

\psline[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=black](5,8)(9,4)
\psline[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=black](11,4)(15,8)

\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=black](4,13)(7.5,5.5)
\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=black](10,2)(7.5,5.5)

\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=red](10,2)(12.5,5.5)
\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=red](12.5,5.5)(16,13)

\psrotate(0,0){-20}{\pspolygon*[](-1.95,13.9)(-0.95,14.9)(0.05,13.9)(-0.95,12.9)}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The last object (inside the psrotate, third line from the bottom) is the one giving me headaches. It took so long to put it there and there will be others like it...

Comment: Do you have an example to show? It might be the case there are better approaches to the one you're using. I'm saying this for those who use `pstricks`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\psdot[dotsize=1.41,dotstyle=square*,dotangle=70](-0.95,13.9)
```

instead of the rotated polygon. By the way, there is a package `pst-optic` with `\psprism`. See pages 21ff of the documentation.

Comment: (+1) I didn't  think of this one :o). However, on compiling I have a small problem: the whole figure is rotated by 90°.Do you know the reason why?

Comment: A problem with the conversion. Pass the option `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` to ghostscript (`ps2pdf`). See Frequently done errors ... No 6 on http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. I kept the original square. The solution is to use the `rotatebox` command. I simplified the code using the `pst-poly` package, which defines a `\PstSquare` command and produces a square not in the same position as yours, so that I had to calculate the resulting rotation.

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks, pst-poly}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}


 \begin{document}

 \begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.1)(20.1,25.1)
\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](0,0)(20,25)
%
\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](1,15)(19,24)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, linewidth=0.06cm,linecolor=gray](5,17)(10,22)(15,17)%prisma
%
\psframe[linewidth=0.065cm,linecolor=black](1,1)(19,14.5)
\pspolygon[linewidth=0.06cm,linecolor=gray](4,2)(10,8)(16,2)%prisma
%
\pscircle*[linecolor=LTCearthred](7.5,5.5){3pt}
\pscircle*[linecolor=LTCearthred](12.5,5.5){3pt}
\pscircle*[linecolor=LTCearthred](10,2){3pt}
%
\psline[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=black](5,8)(9,4)
\psline[linestyle=dotted,linecolor=black](11,4)(15,8)
%
\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=black](4,13)(7.5,5.5)
\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=black](10,2)(7.5,5.5)
%
\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=red](10,2)(12.5,5.5)
\psline[linewidth=0.05cm,linecolor=red](12.5,5.5)(16,13)
%
{\pspolygon*[](-1.95,13.9)(-0.95,14.9)(0.05,13.9)(-0.95,12.9)}
\rput(-0.95,13.9){\rotatebox{-25}{\PstSquare[linecolor =green]}}%{\pspolygon[linecolor =red](-1,0)(0,1)(1,0)(0,-1)}
%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\rput{-25}(-0.95,13.9){\PstSquare[linecolor =green]}` does the same

Comment: @Herbert: That's what I tried first, but as for the O.P., the square moved near the origin. Also tried with `PolyRotation=` – same result. Does it work on your system?

Comment: sure, `\rput` rotates around the given coordinates, no shift!

Comment: Strange… I use MiKTeX. Could there be a difference in the compiler (pdflatex)?

Comment: no, that makes no difference

Comment: May be the option to pass to Ghostscript, as in the comment you've just posted above?